# Location search issue in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

Actually,i stored location value for jquery (availableTags), i want if i search a location that location(in database location 'id' is there) related records only will display, if i click 'Adugodi' means that related location should display so how will fix this please help me.

My script code is:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "Adugodi",
    "Aecs Layout - Itpl",
    "Airport Road",
    "Arekere",
    "Bannergatta Road (Iimb, Bilekalli)",
    "Bannergatta Road (Dairy Circle)",
    "Bannergatta Road (Near Jayadeva, Btm)",
    "Banaswadi",
    "Banashankari",
    "Basavanagudi",
    "Basaveshwara Nagar",
    "Bellandur",
    "Bilekahalli",
    "Biocon, Huskur Gate Electronic City",
    "Bommanahalli",
    "Bommasandra",
    "Btm Layout",
    "Btm Layout 1St Stage",
    "Btm Layout 2Nd Stage",
    "Channasandra - Whitefield",
    "Christ College, Forum Koramangala",
    "Cv Raman Nagar",
    "Dasarahalli-Peenya",
    "Devarabeesanahalli",
    "Doddanekundi",
    "Domlur",
    "Ejipura",
    "Electronic City",
    "Electronic City Phase-1",
    "Electronic City Phase-2",
    "Electronic City (Bommasandra)",
    "Electronic City (Huskur Gate, Biocon)",
    "Ganga Nagar",
    "Global Village",
    "Hal 2Nd Stage",
    "Hebbal",
    "Hegdenagar",
    "Hennur Cross",
    "Hesaraghatta Main Road",
    "Hosa Road",
    "Hoodi - Itpl Whitefield",
    "Hsr Layout",
    "Hbr Layout Nagawara",
    "Hulimavu",
    "Itpl",
    "Itpl Main Road",
    "Indiranagar",
    "Jp Nagar",
    "Jayanagar",
    "Jeevanbhimanagar",
    "Jigani",
    "K R Puram",
    "Kadubeesanahalli",
    "Kadugodi - Whitefield",
    "Kaikondrahalli - Sarjapur",
    "Kalyan Nagar",
    "Kammanahalli",
    "Kasturinagar",
    "Kengeri-Bidadi",
    "Kodihalli",
    "Koramangala",
    "Koramangala - Sony Signal",
    "Koramangala 1St Block",
    "Koramangala 2Nd Block",
    "Koramangala 3Rd Block",
    "Koramangala 4Th Block",
    "Koramangala 5Th Block",
    "Koramangala 6Th Block",
    "Koramangala 7Th Block",
    "Koramangala 8Th Block",
    "Kudlu Gate - Hosur Road",
    "Kumaraswamy Layout",
    "Kundanahalli",
    "Kundanahalli Gate",
    "Kundanahalli Gate [Beml Layout]",
    "Kundanahalli Gate [Shirdi Sai Nagar]",
    "M G Road",
    "Madiwala",
    "Malleshwaram",
    "Manyata Tech Park",
    "Marathahalli",
    "Marathahalli Bridge",
    "Munekolala [Marathahalli]",
    "Mahadevpura",
    "Maruthinagar",
    "Mathikere",
    "Murugeshpalya",
    "Nagavarapalya Main Road (Old Madras Road)",
    "Nagawara",
    "New Bel Road",
    "New Thippasandra",
    "R T Nagar",
    "Ramagondanahalli (Near Forum Valur Mall)",
    "Ramamurthynagar",
    "Rajajinagar",
    "Rajarajeshwarinagar",
    "Rmz Infinity, Old Madras Road",
    "Roopena Agrahara, Hosur Road",
    "Rv College, Mysore Road",
    "S G Palya",
    "Sahakarnagar",
    "Sanjaynagar",
    "Sarjapur Road",
    "Silk Board",
    "Singasandra - Housr Road",
    "Shanthinagar",
    "Tavarekere",
    "Ulsoor",
    "Uttarahalli",
    "Wilson Garden",
    "Whitefield",
    "Yeshwanthpura",
  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
</script>
```

my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group keyword">
                <input type="text" id="tags" placeholder="Search by location" name="location" list="locations" class="searchlocation" style="font-size:18px" />  
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/61a11zmo/

Comment: css is required Maybe. @RamKesavan

Comment: As you require, automatically from database depends on search, right ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "Adugodi",
    "Aecs Layout - Itpl",
    "Airport Road",
    "Arekere",
    "Bannergatta Road (Iimb, Bilekalli)",
    "Bannergatta Road (Dairy Circle)",
    "Bannergatta Road (Near Jayadeva, Btm)",
    "Banaswadi",
    "Banashankari",
    "Basavanagudi",
    "Basaveshwara Nagar",
    "Bellandur",
    "Bilekahalli",
    "Biocon, Huskur Gate Electronic City",
    "Bommanahalli",
    "Bommasandra",
    "Btm Layout",
    "Btm Layout 1St Stage",
    "Btm Layout 2Nd Stage",
    "Channasandra - Whitefield",
    "Christ College, Forum Koramangala",
    "Cv Raman Nagar",
    "Dasarahalli-Peenya",
    "Devarabeesanahalli",
    "Doddanekundi",
    "Domlur",
    "Ejipura",
    "Electronic City",
    "Electronic City Phase-1",
    "Electronic City Phase-2",
    "Electronic City (Bommasandra)",
    "Electronic City (Huskur Gate, Biocon)",
    "Ganga Nagar",
    "Global Village",
    "Hal 2Nd Stage",
    "Hebbal",
    "Hegdenagar",
    "Hennur Cross",
    "Hesaraghatta Main Road",
    "Hosa Road",
    "Hoodi - Itpl Whitefield",
    "Hsr Layout",
    "Hbr Layout Nagawara",
    "Hulimavu",
    "Itpl",
    "Itpl Main Road",
    "Indiranagar",
    "Jp Nagar",
    "Jayanagar",
    "Jeevanbhimanagar",
    "Jigani",
    "K R Puram",
    "Kadubeesanahalli",
    "Kadugodi - Whitefield",
    "Kaikondrahalli - Sarjapur",
    "Kalyan Nagar",
    "Kammanahalli",
    "Kasturinagar",
    "Yeshwanthpura",
  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="form-group keyword">
  <input type="text" id="tags" placeholder="Search by location" name="location" list="locations" class="searchlocation" style="font-size:18px" />  
</div>
```